# How to use proper cross reference in a package

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.4

I am writing a python package and encountered a problem whith cross referencing in a subpackage using pyCharm.

The package structure looks like this:

```
mainpackage/
|
+- __init__.py
|
+- subpackage/
   |
   +- __init__.py
   |
   +- module1.py
   |
   +- module2.py
```

with

```
subpackage/__init__.py:
    from module1 import C1
    from module2 import C2
    print(dir())


module1.py:
    class C1(object):
        pass


module2.py:
    import module1 as md1
    class C2(md1.C1):
        pass
```

Now, pyCharm gives me an 'Unresolved Reference' Error in `__init__.py` and a 'Module not found' Error in `module2.py`. Nevertheless I can run the  `__init__.py` without any errors thrown by the interpreter and it prints out `['C1', 'C2', '__bultins__', ...]`.

What works for pyCharm (what gives me no errors in pyCharm) is:

```
subpackage/__init__.py:
    from .module1 import C1
    from .module2 import C2
    print(dir())


module1.py:
    class C1(object):
        pass


module2.py:
    import subpackage.module1 as md1
    class C2(md1.C1):
        pass
```

This fails when running the `__init__.py` saying: 'SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import'. This also occurs when trying `import mainpackage.subpackage` in another script. Also I learned that using the package/subpackage name within the package itself (as I did in `module2.py`) is wrong.

I shouldn't care about warnings from pyCharm if it works anyway. Though I have two concerns:

1. I cannot access the class definition of C1 by ctrl+click on the parent class of C2 (normally  I can just ctrl+click on `md1.C1` to jump to `module1.py` in the editor)
2. All this makes me think if I might have some flaws in my package buliding approach (`__init__.py`, cross referencing within the package, etc.)

Though those two appear to be different problems, I thought they might have a common solution.

Comment: Pycharm does not have the correct context. It thinks your app start at `mainpackage` (and not `mainpackage/__init__.py`), meaning your import should looks like `from mainpackage.subpackage.module1 import md1`... You can either edit your run to have an execution path as project root, or configure pycharm to [know the correct root folder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html)

Comment: When I had same issues.. I restarted the PyCharm and to my surprise it started working! Best of luck!